# LinkedIn Skills & expertise

Tags: tags, compare, linkedin-api, information-retrieval

I'm looking for details about how linkedIn manages "Search Skills & Expertise". Somebody knows how tags comparison could work? On what algorithms developers could have based the tag comparing system? Something like a "binary independent model" - like? Every supposition or infos are welcome. I'm trying to think about a system that relates tag like linkedIn "Search Skills & Expertise", so I would start with some good incipit, studying some web information retrieval material and asking to someone who knows more than me about this argument.
Thank you.

Comment: Just to confirm, have you asked the LinkedIn folks? They would have the best idea how they've implemented features on their site.  I believe they have a support email address or forum, which may be your channel for communicating with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you asked LinkedIn?

Also they recently released [IndexTank](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/14584603231/linkedin-open-sources-indextank-what-is-indextank-and) as open source sorftware and this is the engine they use for searching and indexing and i suspect that would give you information as you can dow=nload and run it yourself.